# Looking for conditional string-appended values in csv.reader

Tags: python, csv

I have a vendor payables aging report I'm trying to automate which is provided as a .csv file exported from a financial system. In the report, a line called 'functional amount not invoiced' is listed, followed by a $xx.xx amount for each vendor on the list. Below is an example of the report output (with numbers changed):

```
1000000 Vendor1 USD PO Number 1/1/1900
Item1, Description 
100 Each $1.00

INV000000 1/1/1900 000 Each 100 0 $1.00 $24.00
0 0  $24.00

INV000001 1/1/1900 000 Each 50 0 $1.00 $10.50
0 0  $10.50

-------------------
Functional Amount Not Invoiced: $250.00
Amount Not Invoiced Less Returned: $250.00


1000001 Vendor2 USD PO2061994 6/2/2015
Item2, Description 30 Each $38.00

INV000002 7/23/2015 000 Each 9 0 $38.00 $342.00
0 0  $342.00


INV000003 7/23/2015 000 Each 7 0 $38.00 $266.00
0 0  $266.00


-------------------
Functional Amount Not Invoiced: $346,955.00
Amount Not Invoiced Less Returned: $1,245.00
```

I would like to know how I can parse a .csv file for all instances of 'Functional Amount Not Invoiced' greater than or equal to $10,000.00, and in those cases, take the first two strings and return them (in the case above, I would return 1000000 Vendor1). Here's my code so far:

```
companyList={'1000000':'Vendor1',...}

with open('Vendor Report.csv',mode='r',encoding='latin1') as file:
csvreader=csv.reader(file)
for row in csvreader:
    print(' '.join(row))
    if 'Functional Amount Not Invoiced:' in row:
        ...
```

I've gotten to the ... part, and I know the logic is 'if amount after string is at least $10,000.00, find the vendor ID and vendor name and return them. The goal would be to have a list of all vendors over $10,000.00 appended automatically to a list. My expected output would be as follows:

```
Vendor ID Vendor Name $346,955.00
...
```

Comment: This isn't a CSV file (that is a columnar file) and the csv module won't help.

Comment: THAT is the file you're reading?  That is NOT a CSV file.  It is nothing like a CSV file.  You cannot use the `csv` module to read it.  It's easy enough to parse it, but you'll parse it by hand.  What designates the beginning of a new record?  Is it the "PO Number" line?

Comment: Generally, you'd have to figure out what separates records and use that to find the start of a record, scan and keep lines til "Functional amount..." and then grab the text you want. it might help if you post several more records so we can see if there is a good way to figure out a separator.

Comment: @tdelaney Technically it's exported as a .csv file from my financial system, but I agree that it doesn't look like a traditional .csv file. I'm just looking for suggestions on how to navigate parsing this thing to identify vendor ID / vendor name. Regular expressions came to mind first.

Comment: @TimRoberts Vendor ID Vendor Name (here 1000000 Vendor1) is the beginning of the block, and Amount Not Invoiced Less Returned... is the last line of the block. Sometimes there will be 20 or so items that fill the space in between, with maybe 10 invoices listed. But the Vendor ID Vendor Name strings and Amount Not Invoiced... will always be the beginning and end.

Comment: @tdelaney I added another vendor line showing multiple item / invoice lines, the document basically looks like this for about 50 vendors.

Comment: @jon bon journo, how would look like *your expected output* ? Can you add it to your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, here is one option with [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) by using [`read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html) and [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) :

```
#pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

MIN_AMOUNT = 10000

df = pd.read_fwf("input.csv", header=None)
​
vendor_vals = df[0].str.extract(r"(\d+) ([a-zA-Z]+\d+)", expand=False).ffill()
fani_vals = (df.pop(0).str.extract(r"Functional Amount Not Invoiced: \$(.*)",
                expand=False).replace({r",|\.0+": ""}, regex=True).astype(float))
​
companyList = (
                df.assign(VENDOR = vendor_vals, FANI = fani_vals).dropna()
                  .loc[lambda df_: df_["FANI"].gt(MIN_AMOUNT)].to_dict("list")
               ) 
​
```

Output :

```
>>> print(companyList)

{'VENDOR': ['1000001 Vendor2'], 'FANI': [346955.0]}
```

***Update*** :

If you need a dataframe (*to make a .csv*), use this :

```
df = pd.read_fwf("input.csv", header=None)
​
out = (
        df.join(df[0].str.extract(r"(\d+) ([a-zA-Z]+\d+)")
                .rename(columns={0: "VENDOR_ID", 1:"VENDOR_NAME"}).ffill())
          .assign(FANI = lambda df_: df_.pop(0).str.extract(r"Functional Amount Not Invoiced: \$(.*)",
                expand=False).replace({r",|\.0+": ""}, regex=True).astype(float))
          .dropna().loc[lambda df_: df_["FANI"].gt(MIN_AMOUNT)].reset_index(drop=True)
       )
```

Output :
​

```
>>> print(out)

  VENDOR_ID VENDOR_NAME      FANI
0   1000001     Vendor2  346955.0
```

Comment: I edited my question to show expected output, which you guessed correctly. I used your code and added an encoding='latin1' line (it gave me a UTF-8 error otherwise), and received the following message: 'ValueError: cannot call `vectorize` on size 0 inputs unless `otypes` is set'. The difference being that my original file is nominally a .csv file instead of a .txt file in your example.

Comment: That's not a problem, `read_fwf` can open both. Can you tell in which line the error occurs ? Also, in your real dataset, do you have literally Vendor1, Vendor2, .. or real vendor names ?

Comment: I updated the regex pattern to be more generic and also added another approach (*in case you need a real .csv as an output*) ;)

Comment: If the *ValueError* occurs at the line where we instantiate `df`, can you try `df = pd.read_fwf("input.csv", header=None, sep="|")`?

Comment: So if I add encoding='latin1', the error happens at the df.join(df[0]... line, where I get 'ValueError: cannot call `vectorize` on size 0 inputs unless `otypes` is set'. Depends how far you want to take this, you've been very helpful and if need be I can do troubleshooting myself on what you've provided.

Comment: You're welcome. I think you missed a detail when describing your file because if you run my two codes with the given example in your question, no error occurs. I'll update my answer in case you come up with further details ;) To debug, you can start already by printing `df` right after we use `read_fwf` to make sure that the dataframe has only one column called `0`.